# Desktop class in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, awt, javafx-8

I'm trying to integrate a JavaFX WebView into my application.

The problem is that I want to open links in the default browser and not in the WebView.

I googled a lot and everyone is talking about the Desktop class, so I gave it a try.

Here is my relevant code now:

```
webView.getEngine().locationProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> webView.getEngine().loadContent(content.get()));
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            BrowserOpener.open(newValue);
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            });
```

However, it seems working but there is one problem. webView.getEngine().locationProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> webView.getEngine()
                            .loadContent(content.get()));
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            BrowserOpener.open(newValue);
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            });
```

BrowserOpener:

```
public static void open(String uriString) {
    openUri(URI.create(uriString));
}
public static void openUri(URI uri) {
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it seems working but there is one problem. If I run this application and click on a link, the default browser opens the link but here's the problem. Also the Windows File Manager is opening.

If I change the `BrowserOpener.open(newValue)` to `BrowserOpener.open("http://google.com")` it's working fine.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you log the `newValue` string, and post some examples of values that get opened by the Windows file manager?

Comment: I already did the debugging. The newValue contains exactly the same value as the constant. Also I inserted a newValue.equals(constant) and its true.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it behaves that way with `java.awt.Desktop#browse(URI)`, but I've found that there is a native JavaFX solution using the `HostServices` class. Since you're using JavaFX, it may be a better idea anyway. Here's an example I just tried :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BrowseTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        HostServices host = getHostServices();
        host.showDocument("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Note that, as far as I know, you can only get the `HostServices` from your JavaFX `Application`'s `getHostServices()` method.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can only use HostServices if you're running the JavaFX application embedded in a Web page (Applet).

Comment: I tried it and the same problem occured. Even I tried to downgrade my Java to 8u11 from 8u20 since I have a pipeline problem when I close the JavaFX application. (maybe a bug, because it seems like it isnt appearing now)